# Nutch showing following errors, what to do

Tags: nutch

```
enter code here

npun@nipun:~$ nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 2 -topN 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nutch/crawl/Crawl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.  Program will exit.
```

but when i run nutch from terminal it show

Usage: nutch [-core] COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
  crawl             one-step crawler for intranets

etc etc.....

please tell me what to do

Hey Tejasp i did what u told me, i changed the NUTCH_HOME=/nutch/runtime/local/bin also the crawl.java file is there but when i did this

```
 npun@nipun:~$ nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 2 -topN 10
 [Fatal Error] nutch-site.xml:6:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX]           [mM][lL]" is not allowed.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:     The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1168)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1040)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:980)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:405)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:59)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1079)
... 10 more
```

it showed me this result now what...?

also i checked nutch-site.xml file i have done the following edits in it

```
 <configuration>
 <property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>PARAM_TEST</value><!-- Your crawler name here -->
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

Sir, i did as you told me, this time i compiled nutch with 'ant clean runtime' and nutch home is

```
    NUTCH_HOME=/nutch/runtime/deploy/bin

    NUTCH_CONF_DIR=/nutch/runtime/local/conf
```

and now when i run the same command it is giving me this error

```
  npun@nipun:~$ nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 2 -topN 10
  Can't find Hadoop executable. Add HADOOP_HOME/bin to the path or run in local mode.
```

All i want to create a search engine which can search certain thing from certain websites, for my final year project....

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in Nutch version 2.x the name of the Crawl class has changed to Crawler.
I'm using Hadoop to run Nutch, so I use the following command for crawling:

```
hadoop jar apache-nutch-2.2.1.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler urls -solr http://<ip>:8983 -depth 2
```

If you crawl using Nutch on its own, the nutch script should reference the new class name.

Answer (score 1):

> but when i run nutch from terminal it show

This verifies that the `NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch` script is present at the correct location.

Please export `NUTCH_HOME` and `NUTCH_CONF_DIR`

Which mode of nutch are you trying to use ?

1. **local mode** : jobs run without hadoop. you need to have nutch jar inside NUTCH_HOME/lib. Its named after the version that you are using . eg. for nutch release 1.3, the jar name is nutch-1.3.jar.
2. **hadoop mode** : jobs run on hadoop cluster. you need to have nutch job file inside NUTCH_HOME. its named after the release version eg. nutch-1.3.job

If you happen to have these files (corresponding to the mode), then extract those and see if the Crawl.class file is indeed present inside it.

If Crawl.class file is not present, then obtain the new jar/job file by compiling the nutch source.

**EDIT:**

1. Dont use `ant jar`. Use `ant clean runtime` instead. The output gets generated inside `NUTCH_INSTALLATION_DIR/runtime/local` directory. Run nutch from there. That will be your `NUTCH_HOME`
2. Export the required variables `JAVA_HOME, NUTCH_HOME and NUTCH_CONF_DIR` before running.
3. I am getting a feeling that the Crawl.class file is not present in the jar. Please extract the jar and check it out. FYI: Command to extract a jar file is `jar -xvf <filename>`
4. If after #2, you see that class file aint present in the jar, then see if the nutch source code that you downloaded has the java file. ie. `nutch-1.x\src\java\org\apache\nutch\crawl\Crawl.java` If not present, get it from internet and rebuild nutch jar.
5. If after #2, the jar file has class file and you see the issue again, then something is wrong with the environment. Try out some other command like [inject](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_inject). Look for some errors in the hadoop.log file. Let me know what you see.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i complied nutch source by command "npun@nipun:/nutch$ ant jar"  and jar was built in build folder, so i copied it in the dir u said ie lib but it still not work giving the same o/p as earlier...so now what shall i do?

Comment: hey, one correctin, in step #1, use 'ant clean runtime' instead of 'ant clean deploy'. So far, what have u tried ? What error u see after performing the steps given above ?